# Order of Dates in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I have following table which records employee's attendance in a company.

```
    CREATE TABLE EMP_ATNDNC
    (
    WORK_DAY    DATE                         NOT NULL,
    EMP_ID      VARCHAR2(20)                 NOT NULL,
    STATUS      VARCHAR2(1)   DEFAULT '0'    NOT NULL,
    TMSTMP      TIMESTAMP,
    RCRD_VER    TIMESTAMP                    NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT  EMP_ATNDNC_PK PRIMARY KEY(WORK_DAY,EMP_ID),
   CONSTRAINT  EMP_ATNDNC_FK_DAY FOREIGN KEY(WORK_DAY) REFERENCES SCHOOL_OPEN_RCRD(WORK_DAY),
   CONSTRAINT  EMP_ATNDNC_FK_ID FOREIGN KEY(EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMP_RCRD(EMP_ID)
   );
```

As of now, it has two records:

```
    WORK_DAY    EMP_ID     STATUS           TMSTMP                             RCRD_VER
    29-SEP-16     1234       0      27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM       27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM
    26-AUG-16     9999       0      26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM       26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM
```

If I run this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM EMP_ATNDNC WHERE WORK_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-AUG-16') AND TO_DATE('30-SEP-16');
```

I get only this record:

```
    WORK_DAY    EMP_ID     STATUS           TMSTMP                          RCRD_VER
    29-SEP-16     1234       0      27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM     27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM
```

Also If I run this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM EMP_ATNDNC ORDER BY WORK_DAY ASC;
```

I get this result:

```
    WORK_DAY    EMP_ID     STATUS           TMSTMP                             RCRD_VER
    29-SEP-16     1234       0      27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM       27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM
    26-AUG-16     9999       0      26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM       26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM
```

Instead of:

```
    WORK_DAY    EMP_ID     STATUS           TMSTMP                             RCRD_VER
    26-AUG-16     9999       0      26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM       26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM
    29-SEP-16     1234       0      27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM       27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It does not make any sense that this is happening.  But since you wrote in a comment that there was a typo in your question, this means that what you are showing us is not a direct copy-paste of your stuff, but it has undergone some editing before posting.  The mistake is probably in that editing.  The devil is in the details.

Comment: Agree with @MikeNakis above.  Neither issue of yours makes sense.  The only other possibility I can imagine is some kind of corrupted index on `work_day`

Comment: @MikeNakis Actually before posting this question I tried doing it with both '30-SEP-2016' and '30-SEP-16' .

Comment: Can you check your existing values with `select to_char(work_day, 'SYYYY-MM-DD') from emp_atndnc`? It looks like the century is wrong - possibly an insert was done with a YY mask making the year 0016?

Comment: @Gerrat, yes you are right.  the problem was due to the corrupted index. I dropped the table and re-created it and it works fine with my queries.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have dates which are not in the current century, possibly through them being inserted with an incorrect format model. (There isn't really any reason to still be using two-digit years any more...)

To demonstrate, with you table definition:

```
insert into EMP_ATNDNC
values (to_date('26-AUG-16', 'DD-MON-RRRR'), 9999, 0,
  to_timestamp('26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
  to_timestamp('26-AUG-16 04.50.04.628000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'));

insert into EMP_ATNDNC
values (to_date('29-SEP-16', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1234, 0,
  to_timestamp('27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
  to_timestamp('27-AUG-16 05.38.46.022000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'));

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF3 AM';

SELECT * FROM EMP_ATNDNC WHERE WORK_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-AUG-16') AND TO_DATE('30-SEP-16');

WORK_DAY  EMP_ID               S TMSTMP                    RCRD_VER                
--------- -------------------- - ------------------------- -------------------------
26-AUG-16 9999                 0 26-AUG-16 04:50:04.628 PM 26-AUG-16 04:50:04.628 PM

WORK_DAY  EMP_ID               S TMSTMP                    RCRD_VER                
--------- -------------------- - ------------------------- -------------------------
29-SEP-16 1234                 0 27-AUG-16 05:38:46.022 PM 27-AUG-16 05:38:46.022 PM
26-AUG-16 9999                 0 26-AUG-16 04:50:04.628 PM 26-AUG-16 04:50:04.628 PM
```

If you look at the two insert statement one is converting the two-digit year using RRRR, which makes some (usually helpful) assumptions about the century, in this case treating '16' as '2016'; the second is using YYYY which is harsher.

If you query the actual dates using a full-year format model you'll see the difference:

```
select to_char(work_day, 'SYYYY-MM-DD') as work_day, emp_id from emp_atndnc order by work_day;

WORK_DAY    EMP_ID             
----------- --------------------
 0016-09-29 1234                
 2016-08-26 9999
```

The problem isn't really with your query (though that is using two-digit years and implicit conversions relying on your session's NLS settings too, which @TimBiegeleisen pointed out isn't a good idea).

The real problem is with the data. You may be able to correct it - if you are also willing to make assumptions, e.g. adding 2000 years to anything before this century.

But really you also need to find out where that bad data came from, and stop it happening. It's likely you have an insert that is relying on implicit date conversion from a string, and different users or applications have different NLS settings - specifically NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

You should never rely on implicit data conversions that rely on NLS settings. And you shouldn't really be using two-digit years any more, though that may be out of your control.

Comment: Sure, I will keep that in mind. However as pointed out by Gerrat in the comments the problem was due to the corrupted index. I dropped the table and re-created it and it works fine with my queries

Comment: Your second query (with order by) wouldn't usually use an index. How did you determine an index was corrupt, and if it was, why didn't you just recreate that? When you recreated the table how did you repopulate it? Did you look at the full years in the old table?

Answer (score 1):

The second date in your `BETWEEN` clause has the year specified as a two digit number:

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-AUG-2016') AND TO_DATE('30-SEP-16');
                                                   ^^
```

Assuming that your default date format is `dd-mon-yyyy` making the following change *might* work:

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-AUG-2016') AND TO_DATE('30-SEP-2016');
```

However, as the [documentation](http://BETWEEN%20TO_DATE('24-AUG-2016')%20AND%20TO_DATE('30-SEP-16');) for `TO_DATE` mentions:

> It is good practice always to specify a format mask (fmt) with TO_DATE

So ideally you should explicitly mention the date format you are using, e.g. as in this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP_ATNDNC
WHERE WORK_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-AUG-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy') AND
                       TO_DATE('30-SEP-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Comment: No, It didn't help. Still getting same result

Comment: **'30-SEP-2016'** was actually a typo in my question. I have corrected the same. I tried 'SELECT * FROM EMP_ATNDNC WHERE WORK_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-AUG-16', 'dd-mon-yy') AND                     TO_DATE('30-SEP-16', 'dd-mon-yy');' but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Steve Have a look [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/f_to_date.htm).  My query should work AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, However as pointed out by Gerrat in the comments the problem was due to the corrupted index. I dropped the table and re-created it and it works fine with my queries

Comment: @Steve Fair enough, but I think my general comments about `TO_DATE` are valid so I will leave this up in case anyone else has your problem but it is not due to a corrupted index.